# Gnuplot: Error "all points y value undefined" during plotting

Tags: function, plot, gnuplot

I want to plot the following function:

```
f(x)=250*x/(log(0.2*x)-log(log(1/10+1)))

plot f(x)
```

Now I get the error: all points y value undefined!

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You already got the correct answer, but may I give you an advice for future questions/problems? If you run into error messages, try to reduce the command that is causing the error step by step, until the error goes away. In your case I would delete the second part and try `plot 250x/(log(0.2x)`. This will still raise an error, so I would cut the denominator and simply try `plot 250x`. In this way I could find out that I am missing the `*`. Then I would stepwise increase the complexity of the function and proceed likewise.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to write `250*x` and `0.2*x`.
Furthermore, you stepped into one of gnuplot's "meanest pitfalls": integer division, i.e. `1/10 = 0`.
So, as a consequence, the last term would be `log(log(1)) = log(0)`, which leads to "*all points y value undefined!*". Instead, if at least one number is floating point you will get the expected result: `1/10. = 0.1` or `1./10 = 0.1`

So, I assume your function wanted to be: `f(x) = 250*x/(log(0.2*x)-log(log(1/10.+1)))`

**Code:**

```
reset session

set samples 200

f(x) = 250*x/(log(0.2*x)-log(log(1/10.+1)))

plot f(x)
```

**Result:** (assuming f(x) is the intended formula)

[image]